# Raw Query Returning an error

Tags: android, sqlite, fts3

Shouldn't this work just fine?

```
Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " +     KEY_NAME + " = \'chaman\'",, null);
```

I don't know but I get an error when I try to call

```
cursor.getString(1);
```

it says
     CursorIndexOutofBoundsException

I've created my table using

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " USING fts3 (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ADDRESS
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT     NULL, "
                + KEY_BALANCE + " DOUBLE);");
```

&
I'm sure chaman exists in my table as I can view it there in my database.

What's wrong? Please help me out. I'm stuck here for the last 1 hour. :/

Comment: Please post all of your LogCat errors.

Comment: Don't escape single quotes using \ just put them as they are.

Comment: Okay. I used to think that cursor.moveToFirst just checks whether cursor = null or not by seeing if the first element is empty. But thank you people. :)

Comment: @ShivamMangla : A `Cursor` is always initially positioned at index -1 (i.e., before the first record which is actually at index 0). The reason for this is the query mechanism has no idea which record you want (1st, 2nd, last etc). Always explicitly check that the cursor is not null and check the boolean result of `moveToFirst()` to ensure the cursor has at least 1 record to access.

Comment: btw escape character \ .. Isn't this a JAVA thing?
I think it is required & it works fine this way now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CursorIndexOutOfBoundException means you either forgot to call `moveToFirst()` *or* you did call `moveToFirst()` but you didn't check its result (i.e. the Cursor is empty)...

Answer (score 0):

You need make a call to [`moveToFirst`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29)

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {  // returns false if no results
  // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to check the cursor count using `cursor.getCount()` and if the count > 0, then do `moveToFirst`, then you try to access the element using `cursor.getString(1)`